# What is a mosque?

Tags: masjid, definitions

Assalam aleykum.

What are the signs and requirements for a place to be considered a mosque? 
For example. If people gather together in some any room for a prayer. Can the room be considered a mosque? 

***We ask for evidence***
Please don't give answers like yes or no. Please don't say that the Imam says yes or no. Please don't say there is a scholar agreement on this question and they say yes or no. If anybody has no evidence we are not interested in their opinion. If they do have evidence then tell the evidence instead of just opinion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

walaykum salam

A masjid is a place where sujud (prostration) is made. Hence the **masjid** and **sujud** similarities.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a building, since the Prophet is reported to have said:

> الأَرْضُ كُلُّهَا مَسْجِدٌ إِلاَّ الْمَقْبَرَةَ وَالْحَمَّامَ
>
> The whole earth is a masjid, except for the graveyards and washrooms.
>
> [(Sunan Abu Dawud)](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/102)

So the whole earth, excluding graveyards/washrooms, are considered places of prostration (masjids).  If you gather people in a room for prayer, then technically it can be considered a masjid.

Yet, the Prophet praised building structures where believers can come and remember Allah:

> "Whoever builds a masjid even like a sparrow's nest or smaller for Allah, Allah will build for him a house in Paradise."
>
> [(Sunan ibn Majah)](http://sunnah.com/ibnmajah/4/4)

And these structures must only be maintained by believers, as Allah said:

> The masjids of Allah are only to be maintained by those who believe in Allah and the Last Day and establish prayer and give zakah and do not fear except Allah , for it is expected that those will be of the guided.
>
> Surah at-Tawba 9:18